# How to customize webpack's 4 default output chunk name?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

In a minimal configuration like below, how does a webpack newbie change the default output script name?

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/myapp.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/js'),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "lib",
                    chunks: "all"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding the 'default' cache group with customized priority and name but I always ended up having **main.js** in the output scripts.

My goal is to split the sources in two files with - **lib.js** and **app.js**, regardless of their size and other optimization options webpack might consider when splitting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to provide a `name` for your entry file, which you havn't. Webpack defaults to main.js in this case.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "app": "./src/myapp.js"
    },
    ... // Your other stuff

}
```